# php header url as a variable obtained by $_GET["link"] or $_POST["link"]

Tags: php, html

I am trying to redirect page that can redirect crossdomain but I want to be able to change the destination domain as many times as i want without opening up and editing the `php` manually.

To give an e.g. Domain-A redirects to domain-B but I want to be able to change the target, domain-B to domain-C and so domain-A now redirects to domain-C. Can I do this via a form? I think I need to have the header as a variable but can't get it to work. something like: `header("location:".$new_url)`.

Comment: So you want to be able to edit where it redirects to without editing code? You will need either a basic database like SQLite or save a local JSON file on the disk so you can store where that URL will point to once you change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both a `GET` or a `POST` request. Here's an example with `GET`:

URL:

```
example.com/?redirect=new-domain.com
```

Code:

```
header("Location: " . $_GET['redirect']);
```